# Getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error Amazon MWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-mws

I using Reports request to get the reports,

But when I run the code it gives me error below:

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method."

I have try the request in scratchpad and its working fine so there is no problem of any keys.Below is my code:

```
         agent
        .post(`https://mws.amazonservices.com/`)
        .query({
            AWSAccessKeyId:accesskeyid,
            Action:'GetReport',
            Merchant:sellerid,
            MWSAuthToken:token,
            SignatureVersion:2,
            Timestamp:'2019-05-21T07:34:45Z',
            Version:'2009-01-01',
            Signature:'1WN378L846Cts2oJGnJCPoT1nGjYoFcnlLXlZNxABg0=',
            SignatureMethod:'HmacSHA256',
            ReportId:'14941942615018036'
        })
        .then(res=>(this.setState({category:res.text},()=>{
            console.log('category==>',this.state.category)
        })))
```

I have researched a lot but didn't sort out what the actual problems.Kindly someone suggest how to fix it

Comment: How are you generating signature? Please have a look see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html to check correct method to obtain signature string value.

Comment: I copied the signature and other parameters from scratpad netwerk tab

Comment: But for try I  send request to finances api with above parameters with url of finances it worked,

Comment: Signature is hash of payload in which timestamp is a component so for same payload timestamp can't be same and changed timestamp will lead to change in signature.

Comment: So what can be the appropriate solution to this?

Comment: you need to invest some time reading https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_SigningQueryRequest.html, which will give you solution that how to implement signing process.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs for [signing a query request](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_SigningQueryRequest.html).  If you can, use one of the client libraries which also sign requests for you automatically.

Scratchpad will work because it is calculating a signature for you, but you can't copy that signature out and use it elsewhere.